# Load a .rda file and iterate over its objects

Tags: r, rda

I loaded a rda file which basically its a list of dataframes. 
How do I iterate over is objects?

```
>load(data)
>attach(data)
 The following objects are masked _by_ .GlobalEnv:

GSE109597, GSE18897, GSE32575, GSE53232, GSE55205, GSE69039,
GSE83223, GSE87493, GSE98895
> R » objects()
[1] "GSE109597" "GSE18897"  "GSE32575"  "GSE53232"  "GSE55205"  "GSE69039" 
[7] "GSE83223"  "GSE87493"  "GSE98895"
```

Comment: Is `data` the path to the rda file? The `load()` command will return a vector with the names of all the objects loaded. You can use `mget()` to get a list of all those objects: `objs  <- load(data); myobjs <- mget(objs)`. I would discourage you from using `attach()`. It's not a very good practice and it looks like you may have already done it a few times without properly calling `detach()` hence the warning message.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two thoughts:

1. Load explicitly into a new empty environment, then work on them there:

   ```r
   e <- new.env(parent = emptyenv())
   load(filename, envir = e)
   out <- eapply(e, function(x) {
     # do something with x
   })
   ```
2. From [`?load`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.5.3/topics/load), it returns a *"character vector of the names of objects created, invisibly"*. If you capture the (invisible) vector, you should be able to do something like:

   ```r
   nms <- load(data)
   for (nm in nms) {
     x <- get(nm)
     # do something with x
     # optional, save it back with assign(nm, x)
   }
   # or to capture all data into a list (similar to bullet 1 above)
   out <- lapply(lapply(nms, get), function(x) {
     # do something with x
   })
   ```

I prefer the first (environment-based) solution for a few reasons:

- it will *never* overwrite anything in `.GlobalEnv` ... having learned that the hard way some times with **unreproducible issues**, this is huge for me
- it encourages a list-like way of doing things, more important when most or all of the objects in the `.rda` file are the same "thing" (e.g., frame, list) and I plan on doing the same actions to each of them
- if there is ever any doubt as to the source of the data, it won't clutter any of my namespace or global environment